# Building Bazel on IBM lsf.conf

Tags: build, redhat, bazel, lsf

I am trying to build Bazel on IBM (Redhat 6.9) that uses LSF for the job submission system. In the middle of the build, I get an error:

```
lsb_init: initenv_:fopen(/etc/lsf.conf)
```

The `LSF_ENVDIR` is correctly set to where the lsf config files are located. However,  it still looks in there. Can I change this behavior somehow or tell the Bazel build scripts that `lsf.conf` is somewhere else? In case it helps, I have to submit an interactive job to be able to compile. Otherwise, the build process does not start at all and I do not know why (I receive no error massage).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting LSF_SERVERDIR, LSF_LIBDIR and LSF_BINDIR in addition to LSF_ENVDIR.

Comment: All of those are also set correctly but I get the same error.

Comment: Is it possible that some where along the process chain, something is unsetting these environment variables?

Comment: Well, I am not sure. From the system, it should not be since any job will inherit the env from the main caller. Anyhow, I tried it in another machine with a similar system to compile tensorflow and use the binaries.